# Is it important that the four tires have the same mark on the sidewall?

Tags: tires, maintenance, wheels, sidewall

I bought 4 new tires and i noticed that the rear tires have an "outside " mark on the sidewall but the front tires have an "inside" mark,
Is this right ??

Answer (score 3):

Tires marked with an "outside" need to have that mark facing you. "inside" marks needs to be facing the car.

If you look at the tread pattern, it is asymetrical. It looks like the manufacturer is trying to make the tire quieter, but this will only work if the part of the tread meant to be outside is actually facing outside.
[image: Dunlop Vuero VE303]

It sounds like the shop that installed your tires didn't know about this and installed 2 of your tires backwards.

Comment: Did you mean that the same tire have an outside and inside mark ??

Comment: @Saydeh Mine do. Which brand of tires are these?

Comment: Dunlop veuro ve303

Comment: @Saydeh Updated my answer with specifics and a picture

Comment: Ok 10xx, i read your comment, and i understood that the 2 tires installed backwards are installed in a wrong way